# adding widget dynamically in qt

Tags: c++, qt

I have a small problem with adding widget to QMainWindow. 
When i do it like that:

```
wsk_mainStatki = new mainStatki(this);
wsk_mainStatki ->setGeometry(0,0,400,300);
this->layout()->addWidget(wsk_mainStatki);
```

it's ok but i get warning:

> QMainWindowLayout::addItem: Please use the public QMainWindow API instead

this is my game class

```
    #include "game.h"

    game::game()
    {
        setGeometry(200, 200, 400, 300);
        setWindowTitle("Statki");
        wsk_mainStatki = new mainStatki(this);
        wsk_mainStatki ->setGeometry(0,0,400,300);
        this->layout()->addWidget(wsk_mainStatki);
    }
```

game header

```
#ifndef WIDGET1_H
#define WIDGET1_H
#include "k_plansza.h"
#include "mainStatki.h"
#include "settings.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include <QMainWindow>

class game : public QMainWindow
{
    public:
        game();
        ~game() {};
    private:
        mainStatki *wsk_mainStatki;
        settings *wsk_settings;
};

#endif // WIDGET1_H
```

mainstatki class

```
#include "mainstatki.h"

mainStatki::mainStatki(QWidget *parent){
    setupUi(this);
    connect(closeButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), parent, SLOT(close()));
}
```

mainstatki header

```
#ifndef MAINSTATKI_H
#define MAINSTATKI_H

#include <QWidget>
#include "ui_mainStatki.h"

class mainStatki : public QWidget, public Ui::mainStatki
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    mainStatki(QWidget *parent);

};

#endif // MAINSTATKI_H
```

How it should look?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I believe it means you are not expected to manually insert stuff into the layout of a QMainWindow, but instead use methods like addToolBar, setStatusBar or setCentralWidget. The layouting of your own widgets would happen in the centralWidget.

By the way, your mainStatki constructor is missing a call to the QWidget constructor. Unless you have a good reason not to do it, your constructor should rather look like this:

```
mainStatki::mainStatki(QWidget *parent)
    : QWidget(parent)
{
    setupUi(this);
    connect(closeButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), parent, SLOT(close()));
}
```