# How to add a widget to QMainWindow layout?

Tags: c++, qt, layout, qmainwindow

I'm using the code below to add a QPushButton to a ui:

```
    QPushButton *mine[PlayForm->horizontal][PlayForm->vertical];
    for(int i=0; i<PlayForm->horizontal; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<PlayForm->vertical; j++)
        {
            QWidget wdg;
            mine[i][j] = new QPushButton(" ", &wdg);
            mine[i][j]->setGeometry(size*i, size*j, size, size);
            mine[i][j]->show();
            PlayForm->layout()->addWidget(mine[i][j]);
        }
    }
```

But I get this message:

> QMainWindowLayout::addItem: Please use the public QMainWindow API instead

What should I do?

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: QMainWindowLayout::addItem: Please use the public QMainWindow API instead
this is my problem and I don't know what should I do

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are creating a *temporary* parent widget on the stack, and using a reference to it for the `QPushButton` - this is a fine way to get a segfault.

The parent widget argument defaults to `nullptr`, which is acceptable for you as the layout takes ownership of it.

```
//QWidget wdg;
mine[i][j] = new QPushButton( " " );
```

The error message you are getting is answered by this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4178829/adding-widget-dynamically-in-qt).  In short it means that you should not modify the `QMainWindow` layout; you need to a create a widget, add that as the central widget, and then modify the central widget's layout.

Comment: thanks. but I'm not sure I'm understanding correctly. If I use pointer to `QPushButton` and then new that, this is correct?

Comment: I saw that link before ask question, but I didn't get it. Could you explain that?