# Error in Qt: QMainWindowLayout::addItem: Please use the public QMainWindow API instead

Tags: c++, qt, layout

```
for (int x = 0; x < size; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < size; y++) {
            QLineEdit *newEdit = new QLineEdit(" ");
            newEdit->setGeometry(y * 50, x * 25, 50, 25);
            newEdit->setText("0");
            layout()->addWidget(newEdit);
            objMatrix[y + x * size] = newEdit;
        }
    }
```

I am using that code to add widgets dynamicly. Then i get this error:

```
QMainWindowLayout::addItem: Please use the public QMainWindow API instead
```

As many times, as code `layout()->addWidget(newEdit);` has worked.
What should i do to prevent it?

Sorry for my english.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15633709/qmainwindowlayoutadditem-please-use-the-public-qmainwindow-api-instead

Comment: But i did things from that question.

Comment: I told you about setCentralWidget, not a heap or stack.

Comment: Then my program crashes without any errors.

Comment: That was i did: `QWidget *wdg; wdg->layout()->addWidget(newEdit); this->setCentralWidget(wdg);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should work with layouts in another way because in your code widget has not aby layout, so your pointer to layout is bad, so you programm crashes. Try In constructor for example:

```
QWidget *centralWidget = new QWidget(this);   
QGridLayout *layout = new QGridLayout();
centralWidget->setLayout(layout);
        
layout->addWidget(new QPushButton("Button  1"),0,0);
layout->addWidget(new QPushButton("Button  2"),0,1);     
layout->addWidget(new QPushButton("Button  3"),0,2);     
 
setCentralWidget(centralWidget);
```

If you want set position of widgets yourself then you don't need layout at all. Just set centralWidget as parent to all your another widgets and call setGeometry without any issue. Note that in this case top left corner of centralWidget will have 0;0 coordinates for child widgets.

Comment: Is there a layout without auto aligment? I mean, i just want to set X and Y coordinates by myself, not as layout wants.

Answer (score 1):

You must first add central widget in window. And insert widgets in him.

Comment: I did, but then my program crashes without any errors.
(`QWidget *wdg; wdg->layout()->addWidget(newEdit); this->setCentralWidget(wdg);`)

Comment: QWidget *widget = new QWidget();
QVBoxLayout *VBoxLayout = new QVBoxLayout();
widget->setLayout(VBoxLayout);
for (int x = 0; x < size; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < size; y++) {
            QLineEdit *newEdit = new QLineEdit(" ");
            newEdit->setGeometry(y * 50, x * 25, 50, 25);
            newEdit->setText("0");
            widget->layout()->addWidget(newEdit);
            objMatrix[y + x * size] = newEdit;
        }
    }
setCentralWidget(widget);

Comment: Ty, but then my widgets will be not in their places. http://storage8.static.itmages.ru/i/14/1019/h_1413752703_9967623_0bb6765981.png so i can't place them by X and Y coordinates.